# (ILOG) IBM ODM 8.5 Logging a name of the rule in execution time

Tags: java, logging, ibm-odm

I want to create a log such as System.out.println("RuleName : "+ruleName); in IBM ODM rule engine.

So these are what i did;

**1- Create BOM virtual methods which are static and get parameter of instance which is 
the object of ilog.rules.engine.IlrRuleInstance.**

```
instance ilog.rules.engine.IlrRuleInstance
```

**2- Create BOM to XOM mapping by the following**

```
System.out.println("Log icinde");
String ruleName = "";
if (instance != null )
    ruleName = instance.getRuleName();
else
    System.out.println("instance null!");
if (ruleName != null) {
    System.out.println("RuleName: "+ ruleName);
}
return;
```

**3- Call it in rule flow as an initial or final action.**

```
utility.logla(ruleInstance);
```

But when i execute  the flow my log doesnt work instance is ***null*** and ruleName also is ***null***;

How should i configure and set logging feature by using bom. Could you give me an example of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could use Decision Warehouse that is part of the execution server to trace each execution. This can include which rules have been fired during the execution, but depends on what filters you apply.

Here is the documentation on DW and how to set it up: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.res.managing/topics/con_res_dw_overview.html

Comment: Thank you very much I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling the getRuleName() outside of the context of a rule instance within your rule flow, from what I can see from your description.

If you had a BOM method called from within the action of a rule, you could then call [IlrRuleInstance.getRuleName()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.ref.res/html/api/html/ilog/rules/engine/IlrRuleInstance.html#getRuleName%28%29) and it would return the name of the rule (I have done such a thing myself before).

What are you trying to achieve with this logging?

Comment: Thank you for your response but as you told here I can't call that method IlrRuleInstance.getRuleName() in BOM to XOM mapping field. As I see the instance only work on action rules; whatif i want to call it in rule flow in BAL area? Or is there anyway to call it in BAL area in rule flow. The point i want to reach in here call it in BAL area in rule flow by using BOM. And I want to see which rules are activated which are not in run time, that is what i want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way of logging from rules. In your Virtual method, pass the name of the rule itself rather than ruleInstance. You can also verbalize your method and use the same in each rule.

for e.g.:
From BAL:
Log *the name of this rule ;*

From IRL:
Log(ilog.rules.brl.IlrNameUtil.getBusinessIdentifier(?instance.ruleName));

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use the BAL provided above (`the name of this rule`) within the Rule Flow (Orchestration) for your Rule Application or Module.

Of course this solution should be used only for debugging or troubleshooting scenarios.

Hope this helps.